# nvcuda.dllが見つからない

Tags: cuda

PhysXを利用するためにPhysX 3.3.1をインストールしたのですが、

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\AGEIA Technologies\SDK\PhysX-3.3.1_PC_SDK_Core\Bin\win64"
```

内のSamples.exeを実行すると、

> コンピューターにnvcuda.dllがないため、プログラムを開始できません。この問題を解決するためには、プログラムを再インストールしてみてください。

と表示されます。
問題を解決するために、
再インストールやCUDAのインストールも行いました。けれど解決しませんでした。
CUDAからDLLをビルドする必要があるのでしょうか？

Answer (score 1, accepted):

英語版stackoverflowで検索してみると [結構いろいろ出てきます](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=nvcuda.dll) ね。

あまりに基本的なことなので書くのも躊躇われるのですが、 nvidia のグラフィックチップ/カードが搭載された PC 上で実行していますか? またそのドライバが正しくインストールされているでしょうか? 念のため確認してみてください。  
 ([参考: Nvcuda.dll missing?](http://hashcat.net/forum/thread-2220.html))

Comment: 今まで~.dllが見つからない時ダウンロードしてSystem32フォルダに入れ解決していましたが、英語版で[ダンロード](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12594993/emgucv-nvcuda-dll-could-not-be-found/25416715#25416715)してわかりました。ハードウェア構成その物に問題があるということですね。CUDAを利用しない方法を検討します。

Comment: 私も専門ではないので間違っているかもしれませんが、PhysxはCUDA以外では利用できない可能性があります(どちらもnvidiaの戦略的なプロダクトですので)。代わりと言ってはなんですが [Bulletという物理エンジン](http://bulletphysics.org/wordpress/) があるようです。こちらはCUDAの代わりにOpenCLをアクセラレーションに使用するので、ハードウェア構成に依らず利用できると考えられます。

Comment: 同一フォルダにある'SnippetMBPDEBUG.exe'や'SnippetHelloWorldDEBUG.exe'は動作の確認が出来ました。'Samples.exe'のみ利用できませんでしたので、質問しました。

Comment: 推測ばかりで申し訳ないのですが、動いたプログラムについては単に、CUDAを使うまでも無い簡単な(量が少ない)計算だった、ということではないでしょうか。